# Swift: Extract a Substring from a String

Tags: swift, find, substring

I have a String that can be either of the following:

```
tempString = "What? The ID: 54673 Over there"
tempString = "Jump... ID: 4561E how high"
```

Basically, I want to retrieve the five character ID: from the string. I can do this with most languages by finding ID:, adding 4 to it to get to the beginning of the ID:, and then taking the next five characters.

For example, in Excel:

```
=MID("Jump... ID: 4561E how high",FIND("ID:","Jump... ID: 4561E how high")+4, 5)
```

Would = 4561E.

How do we do this with Swift?

Comment: Please add your own attempt at solving this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex approach to find the first 5 characters from [0-9] or [A-F] after "ID: "(used hex letters only if this is not the case you can use A-Z).

```
if let range = string.range(of: "(?<=ID: )[0-9A-F]{5}", options: .regularExpression) {
    let id = string[range]  // 
    // if you need a String instead of a substring
    let stringID = String(string[range])
}
```

---

edit/update:

Looking at your answer it looks like the requirements are totally different from your original post anyway to find an IF compound of 8 hexa characters followed by hyphen then 4 hexa characters followed by hyphen (3 times) than 12 hexa characters you can use the following regex `"([0-9a-f]{8}-)([0-9a-f]{4}-){3}([0-9a-f]{12})"`:

---

```
let dataString = """
{
  "@odata.context": "$metadata#GeoFences(Points())/$entity",
  "ID": "2b2a2abc-5962-4290-92b4-773025ffd50b",
  "Points": {
    "POINT_TYPE": "F",
    "POINT_NUM": 0,
    "LATITUDE": 32.92197686725423,
    "LONGITUDE": -117.04306932263532,
    "parent_ID": "2b2a2abc-5962-4290-92b4-773025ffd50b"
  },
  "GEOFENCE_NAME": "New Fence",
  "GEOFENCE_TYPE": "O",
  "PRIVACY": "X",
  "CENTER_LAT": 32.92043316309709,
  "CENTER_LONG": -117.04286922250975,
  "ZOOM_LAT": 0.006238797350533787,
  "ZOOM_LONG": 0.005345531926053582,
  "PATH_TOLERANCE": 5,
  "ENTRANCE_TOLERANCE": 5
}
"""
```

---

```
if let range = dataString.range(of: "([0-9a-f]{8}-)([0-9a-f]{4}-){3}([0-9a-f]{12})", options: .regularExpression) {
    let id = dataString[range]  // 4561E
    print("ID:", id)
    // if you need a String instead of a substring
    let stringID = String(dataString[range])
    print("stringID:", stringID)
}
```

---

This will print

> ID: 2b2a2abc-5962-4290-92b4-773025ffd50b
>
> stringID: 2b2a2abc-5962-4290-92b4-773025ffd50b

---

Note that your code would result in `"2b2a2abc-5962-4290-92b4-773025ffd50`

---

edit/update2:

Considering that your string is JSON you can simply decode your string id:

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let id: String
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "ID"
    }
}
do {
    let id = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: Data(dataString.utf8)).id
    print(id)  // "2b2a2abc-5962-4290-92b4-773025ffd50b"
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

If you need to decode all your data:

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let odataContext, id: String
    let points: Points
    let geofenceName, geofenceType, privacy: String
    let centerLat, centerLong, zoomLat, zoomLong: Double
    let pathTolerance, entranceTolerance: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case odataContext = "@odata.context", id = "ID", points = "Points", geofenceName = "GEOFENCE_NAME", geofenceType = "GEOFENCE_TYPE", privacy = "PRIVACY", centerLat = "CENTER_LAT", centerLong = "CENTER_LONG", zoomLat = "ZOOM_LAT", zoomLong = "ZOOM_LONG", pathTolerance = "PATH_TOLERANCE", entranceTolerance = "ENTRANCE_TOLERANCE"
    }
}
```

---

```
struct Points: Codable {
    let pointType: String
    let pointNum: Int
    let latitude, longitude: Double
    let parentID: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case pointType = "POINT_TYPE", pointNum = "POINT_NUM", latitude = "LATITUDE", longitude = "LONGITUDE", parentID = "parent_ID"
    }
}
```

---

```
do {
    let root = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: Data(dataString.utf8))
    print("ID:", root.id)  // ID: 2b2a2abc-5962-4290-92b4-773025ffd50b
    print("Root:", root)   // Root: Root(odataContext: "$metadata#GeoFences(Points())/$entity", id: "2b2a2abc-5962-4290-92b4-773025ffd50b", points: __lldb_expr_111.Points(pointType: "F", pointNum: 0, latitude: 32.92197686725423, longitude: -117.04306932263532, parentID: "2b2a2abc-5962-4290-92b4-773025ffd50b"), geofenceName: "New Fence", geofenceType: "O", privacy: "X", centerLat: 32.92043316309709, centerLong: -117.04286922250975, zoomLat: 0.0062387973505337885, zoomLong: 0.005345531926053582, pathTolerance: 5, entranceTolerance: 5)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. My rep is too low for my votes to show, but I am working on that.

Comment: Thanks for throwing the decode in. I will update code to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `range(of:)` on the string to find the `range` of the substring, and then use the `upperBound` of that `range` to index the original string to get the substring starting from that point.  Finally `prefix(5)` allows you to grab the first 5 characters of that substring and `String()` turns the `Substring.Subsequence` back into a normal `String`:

```
if let range = tempString.range(of: "ID: ") {
    let ident = String(tempString[range.upperBound...].prefix(5))
    print(ident)
}
```

**Note:** `range(of:)` comes from the *Foundation* framework, so you need to `import Foundation` or `import` another framework that uses `Foundation` such as `UIKit` or `Cocoa`.

Comment: That's literally what OP asked for. If range is not needed OP can also do `if let index = tempString.range(of: "ID: ")?.upperBound {`

Comment: @LeoDabus, true I considered writing that way as well.

Comment: Wow. An elegant solution. Much better than mine. I had to do some escapes: dataString.range(of: "ID\":\"") 
Thanks.

Comment: @NYReno you can use `#"whatever"#` instead of escaping your string `#"ID":""#`

Answer (score 0):

For your case can use NSRegularExpression:

```swift
let tempString1 = "What? The ID: 54673 Over there"
let tempString2 = "Jump... ID: 4561E how high"

func matches(for regex: String, in text: String) -> [String] {
    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex)
        let results = regex.matches(in: text,
                                    range: NSRange(text.startIndex..., in: text))
        return results.map {
            String(text[Range($0.range, in: text)!])
        }
    } catch let error {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return []
    }
}

var res1 = matches(for: "[0-9]+[A-Z]*", in: tempString1) // 54673
var res2 = matches(for: "[0-9]+[A-Z]*", in: tempString2) // 4561E
```

Comment: This regex it is very lenient. It doesn't care about if the digits are preceded by "ID:", and/or how many digits or letters it is going to match.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I started this exercise because I was too lazy to decode the JSON, because I had to build the structures and get them right. So, I thought that I would quickly do a substring. Well, decoding would have been better and faster and more accurate, but I will show my code below. Basically, I wanted to get the ID from a JSON string:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "$metadata#GeoFences(Points())/$entity",
  "ID": "2b2a2abc-5962-4290-92b4-773025ffd50b",
  "Points": {
    "POINT_TYPE": "F",
    "POINT_NUM": 0,
    "LATITUDE": 32.92197686725423,
    "LONGITUDE": -117.04306932263532,
    "parent_ID": "2b2a2abc-5962-4290-92b4-773025ffd50b"
  },
  "GEOFENCE_NAME": "New Fence",
  "GEOFENCE_TYPE": "O",
  "PRIVACY": "X",
  "CENTER_LAT": 32.92043316309709,
  "CENTER_LONG": -117.04286922250975,
  "ZOOM_LAT": 0.006238797350533787,
  "ZOOM_LONG": 0.005345531926053582,
  "PATH_TOLERANCE": 5,
  "ENTRANCE_TOLERANCE": 5
}
```

My code is as follows. I will replace it with decode soon. the variable id does contain the id.

```
var foundI :Bool = false
var iIndex = 0
for (index, char) in dataString.enumerated() {
    if char == "I" {
        foundI = true
        iIndex = index
    } else if char == "D" {
        if foundI == true && index == iIndex+1 {
           var suffixStr =  String(dataString.dropFirst(iIndex+5))
           var id = String(suffixStr.prefix(36))
        
            print("New String \(id)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: check my post of the regex approach to find the ID

Comment: This would result in "561E" for your second string in your post

Comment: Yes, you are correct, as I did not handle the escape characters. Thanks.
vacawama:
if let range = dataString.range(of: "ID\":\"") {
                    let ident = String(dataString[range.upperBound...].prefix(36))
                    print(ident)
                }